# Kafka Duplicated rows in Bigquery

Tags: apache-kafka, google-bigquery, apache-kafka-connect

I'm SINKing my Postgres database with BigQuery and it's working, but when I insert, update or delete one row (Postgres), it appears in BigQuery 3 rows: one with the insert command, another with the update command and the last with delete.

For example:

1 - after insert

```
Postgres
--------------------
id | name | deleted
--------------------
1  | John |  false
--------------------

BigQuery
--------------------
id | name | deleted
--------------------
1  | John |  false
--------------------
```

2 - after update the name

```
Postgres
--------------------
id | name | deleted
--------------------
1  | Mary |  false
--------------------

BigQuery
--------------------
id | name | deleted
--------------------
1  | John |  false
1  | Mary |  false
--------------------
```

3 - after delete

```
Postgres
--------------------
id | name | deleted
--------------------
1  | Mary |  true
--------------------

BigQuery
--------------------
id | name | deleted
--------------------
1  | John |  false
1  | Mary |  false
1  | Mary |  true
--------------------
```

Could anyone tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: It seems to be an implementation detail of the connector. Yet you didn't tell through what service you connect the PostgreSQL instance to BigQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are using Debezium Postgres Connector which captures all relevant events from the database and creates *new records* for each event.

Not sure if you are expecting BigQuery to exactly match the database, but if that is the case, you likely wouldn't use Kafka Connect since that will almost always insert new records to BigQuery (depending on Connector implementaion details), and would instead use some batch process to periodically import the whole database into BiqQuery